# PL/pgSQL Cursor for rows mod 3

Tags: sql, postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

So I am working in PL/pgSQL and I want to create a function that returns only the data from the rows that are row%3=0 and I need to use a cursor.

I have the following but it is obviously not working

```
create or replace function punto6() returns void AS $$
declare
    rPers personas%ROWTYPE;             
    curs3   CURSOR  IS  select * from personas order by nombres;
BEGIN   
        FOR rPers   IN  curs3   LOOP
        if current of curs3 % 3 =0  THEN
            RAISE   NOTICE  ''Nombre:   %   %'',    rPers.nombres,  
            rPers.apellidos;
        END LOOP;                           
        return;         
end;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Real shame you *need* to use a cursor because there are much better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create or replace function punto6() returns void AS $$
declare
    rPers RECORD;               
    curs3   CURSOR  IS  select * from personas order by nombres;
    numero int;
BEGIN
    numero = 1;
    OPEN curs3;
    LOOP
    FETCH curs3 INTO rPers;
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    if numero % 3 = 0   THEN
        RAISE   NOTICE  'Nombre:    %   %', rPers.nombres,  
        rPers.apellidos;
    END IF;
    numero = numero + 1;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE curs3;
    return;         
end;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```